# Would you please explain me how i can change the drop down list select menu in css.

Tags: html, css

Would you please explain me how i can change the drop down list select menu.
how can i change mouse over color in select option menu in css?

Comment: try atleast putting your code so that everyone can help.

Comment: i have tried in <select style="background-color:green"> but it is change a background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `onmouseout` and `onmouseover`:

```
<select style="background-color:#fff;" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#999';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';">
```